# I accidentally deleted a partition and my system won't boot

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I deleted `/dev/sda3`, and now my system won't boot. I tried to use boot repair; but, it shows me an error message that says

```
GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition
```

I created one but it doesn't work.

[image: Gparted in photo of screen]

The image above shows the `/dev/sda3` partition before it was deleted

This is what it shows now (@Pilot6)

[image: photo of screen showing terminal window below gparted window, hard to read]

Comment: `sda3` is still there. You deleted some other partition. What was there?

Comment: That image was before I deleted it

Comment: Hm. It is not related to Ubuntu. I always delete this kind of partitions with no problem. If you boot from LiveUSB, what does it show now?

Comment: @Pilot6 I'll put the image in the question

Comment: @Pilot6 there it is

Comment: @Pilot6 it can be a root partition as in dev/sda 1 there's my recovery partition

Comment: Hold on, I see what is the problem. you moved the left side of your Ubuntu `/` partition.

Comment: @Pilot6 so what do I do?

Comment: @Pilot6 I remember that when I deleted the partition it said that I would move right something

Answer (score 2):

You moved the first sector of your Ubuntu boot partition. That is why the loader does not know where to find it.

This can be easily fixed.

1. Boot from a LiveUSB.
2. Mount you Ubuntu partition to `/mnt`. I see that you have done that already. But in case you boot again run:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/sda8 /mnt
   sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
   sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
   sudo mount --bind /sys  /mnt/sys
   ```
3. Then chroot and update grub:

   ```
   sudo chroot /mnt
   sudo update-grub
   exit
   ```
4. Reboot to Ubuntu a normal way.

You can also try [Boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). But you need to know that your Ubuntu partition is `sda8` and the EFI partition is `sda6`.

Comment: it tells me that it cannot find a device for /

Comment: it asks me if /dev is mounted

Comment: do I have to do something in gparted?

Comment: Pilot? Please help

Comment: I did that and when I rebooted it didn't work

Comment: I added some more commands.

Comment: It tells me that none of that mount points exist

Comment: Boot again form LiveUSB and do everything from the beginning.

Comment: Look what I did below

Comment: I posted commands to a wrong place.

Comment: Boot repair doesn't work

Comment: What is "does not work"?

Comment: It shows me the error that says GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition

Comment: That means that you boot not in UEFI mode.

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: When I go to the boot menu in bios there's no option to change from legacy to uefi

Comment: Also I used boot repair yesterday and it worked find without the GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition error

Comment: So I figured out and yes I was in UEFI mode

Comment: are you still there? It's not good to talk alone...

Comment: Please I really need the files in Ubuntu help me @Pilot6

Comment: I can't teach you everything. Try to use web search how to boot in UEFI mode. Or re-install Ubuntu, if all that is too hard.

Comment: Sry, I checked and used UEFI mode, still boot repair won't work

Comment: It is too hard to figure out what is the problem. GPT should be OK in UEFI mode.

Comment: Maybe the partition was important

Comment: That partition is not related at all. It is moving of other partitions that causes problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install grub again, run these commands in terminal.

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then follow Pilot6 answer.